# Two nucleons system with total isospin quantum number $T = 1$

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, isospin-symmetry

I am confused with the resolution of this question:

A system of two nucleons is in a state with a total isospin quantum number $T = 1$. What are the possible values for the total spin quantum number $S$ and orbital angular momentum $L$ for this system?

I know that $S$ is 0 or 1, but how can we know the $L$ without knowing the $J$ (total angular momentum $J = L+S)$?

Answer (score 0):

The nucleons are fermions, so for two particles under interchange the state must change sign.  L odd, S=0, and T=0 states all change sign under interchange for two particles.
L even, S=1, and T=1 do not. This restricts the states.